# How to know the root of your website using $_SERVER?

Tags: php

for example is I have a example site in xampp localhost htdocs:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/example
```

and when I view the `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` in a specific .php inside the sub-folder of the root, I will have to use the first string to get the root:
**specific .php inside the subfolder:**

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/example/subfolder/page.php
```

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` **I will get in the .php:**

```
/example/subfolder/page.php
```

but when I try this in a free hosting site, I get this:

```
/subfolder/page.php
```

the root I need in the localhost is:

```
/example/
```

while in a hosting site is:

```
/
```

is there a code to get the root of your website for both localhost and in a hosting site? or is there a hint/flag whatev. it is if I will need to use the first string `/*first_string*/` to get the root in the $_SERVER? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

adding more characters to be able to save the answer....

Comment: then I dont know what you need man... this is your question: "How to know the root folder of your website using $_SERVER?" this is how...

Comment: Your local machine is Windows, and your web server is linux.  That's why you have a discrepancy.  The root is always / from a browser's perspective.

Comment: `The root is always / from a browser's perspective` is not the problem because PHP script is processed by the server, not browser..

Comment: Then you need to erase this question, rephrase it, tell us what you are attempting to do and what you have tried.  Because you're all over the place. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] is the script itself, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is the root of the website (/). even if $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is /this/is/not/the/root/  it is still the root (/) from the browser http:////www.example.com//